# How to interpret significant test of moderators and null percentage of explained variance in meta-analysis using "metafor" package?

Tags: r, metafor, multilevel-analysis

I'm currently working on a meta-analysis of proportions (number of mosquitoes transmitting a disease/number of mosquitoes tested), using `metafor` package (Viechtbauer, 2010). My aim is to compute a summarized effect size for each of 5 mosquitoes species. As far, my analysis strategy is:

- Using PFT (double arcsine) transformation in order to normalize data (I have lots of 0 and 1 as values)
- Running overall model to assess heterogeneity (test for residual heterogeneity significative)
- As I have several measures coming from each of the articles included in the meta-analysis, I assessed the necessity of using a three-level model (LRT significative, for "measure" and "article" (measure nested in article)
- Using subgroup analysis, with mosquitoes species as moderator
- Assessing for residual heterogeneity
- Testing some moderators to try to explain residual heterogeneity

When I performed subgroup analysis, I got a test for moderator significative for the variable "Specie". But I then wanted to know which part of variance is explained by this significative variable, and I obtained -0.9% (truncated at 0%) (I used "pseudo R-squared" method suggested by W. Viechtbauer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356450/getting-r-squared-from-a-mixed-effects-multilevel-model-in-metafor)).

So, my question is: would it be possible/coherent to have a test of moderators significative and no variance explained by this moderator ? How to explain it ?

As I use REML estimation, I can't use LRT to test if the variable is significative (and I would rather not use ML back just to compute LRT).

Thanks in advance if someone can help me,

Best regards,

Alex

If useful, here is a abstract of the code I used:

```
ies.da <- escalc(xi = data_test[, "n"], 
                 ni = data_test[, "n_tested"],
                 data = data, 
                 measure = "PFT", 
                 add = 0)
  
subganal.specie.mv <- rma.mv(yi, vi, 
                             data = ies.da, 
                             mods = ~factor(Specie), 
                             method = "REML",
                             random = ~1|article/measure)

subganal.no.specie.mv <- rma.mv(yi, vi, 
                                data = ies.da, 
                                method = "REML",
                                random = ~1|article/measure)

pseudo.r.squared <- (sum(subganal.no.specie.mv$sigma2) - sum(subganal.specie.mv$sigma2)) / sum(subganal.no.specie.mv$sigma2)
```

As result, I get a test of moderator significative:

```
subganal.specie.mv

Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 165; method: REML)

Variance Components:

            estim    sqrt  nlvls  fixed     factor 
sigma^2.1  0.0184  0.1358     21     no     article
sigma^2.2  0.0215  0.1466    165     no     article/measure 

Test for Residual Heterogeneity:
QE(df = 161) = 897.9693, p-val < .0001

Test of Moderators (coefficients 2:4):
QM(df = 3) = 12.3578, p-val = 0.0063

Model Results:

                  estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub 
intrcpt             0.6172  0.1051   5.8729  <.0001   0.4112   0.8232  *** 
factor(Specie)1    -0.0123  0.1240  -0.0990  0.9211  -0.2554   0.2308      
factor(Specie)2    -0.2110  0.1178  -1.7913  0.0733  -0.4419   0.0199    . 
factor(Specie)3    -0.2299  0.1008  -2.2813  0.0225  -0.4274  -0.0324    *
```

But my "pseudo R squared" is null:

```
pseudo.r.squared
[1] -0.009012437
```